# Meteor loginWithFacebook permissions not being asked

Tags: facebook, meteor

I am using `Meteor.loginWithFacebook`:

```
 Meteor.loginWithFacebook({
      // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/
      requestPermissions: ['read_friendlists','user_about_me','user_birthday',
      'user_education_history', 'user_friends', 'user_likes', 'user_photos',
      'user_religion_politics', 'user_work_history'],
      loginStyle: "popup"
    }, function (err,res) {
      if(err)  alert(err)
      else console.log(res)
    });
```

But when my actual login box pops up, thought the user is logged in and I get access to all their publicly availabe information, it doesn't actually request any of the specified permissions (and I therefore don't have access to them). Is there something in my code I need to change in order to have the permissions actually be requested?

Comment: Despite the Meteor documentation showing the above as the way to do it, it is actually : `Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    facebook: [the_permissons_you_want]
  }
});`

Comment: I think last time I tried. It ddint ask the admin of the Facebook app. Also do you get like a warning message saying that you need these permissions reviewed first in the popup dialog ?

Comment: No (I checked by manually deleting myself from the db and signing up again). So, using `requestPermissions` directly with the `Meteor.loginWithFacebook` function didn't work for me but moving it to `Accounts.ui.config` did.

Answer (score 0):

@kittyminky you right

the solution is

Accounts.ui.config({ requestPermissions: { facebook: [the_permissons_you_want] } });

Comment: I tried migrating `requestPermissions` to `Accounts.ui.config({})` and then trying it both there and `Accounts.loginWithFacebook` but it didn't work for me. Still investigating...

Answer (score 0):

on my case using Accounts.ui.config yields an error since i only have Accounts defined, Accounts.ui isn't defined for me.

Perhaps because i didn't add that package, but must be a way without using the .ui ?